# tweepy search by user + query

Tags: python, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I want to search the whole timeline of a specific user for a particular query

I tried setting the .items() to the total number of tweets in the user profile
but I'm not getting any results back .. any idea on how to solve this issue?

```
username="No_Rumors"
t =" from:No_Rumors"
z= "أمين رابطة العالم الإسلامي يقرع جرس الكنيسة النصرانية"
no_of_tweets = api.get_user(screen_name=username).statuses_count
query=z+t
t  = tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q=query).items(no_of_tweets)
 
for tweet in t:
   print(tweet.text)
```